# MySQL request with WHERE

Tags: php, mysqli

My database is as following:
[image]

What I want to create is a HTML table which only show the data if they meet the following points:

- Select all orders with the first order_number with order_status '1' or '2' (order number will always be higher)

If I use my database example my table should show 2 rows:

- ID 1 and ID 2. Those data I want to select with MySQL.

My code:

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM scan_activities ORDER BY order_number DESC'
```

I don't understand how to make sure MySQL uses the first possible (lowest) order_number for the selection. Also it is important that one specific order_number can have multiple rows. Al those rows should be in the selection ofcourse.

Comment: Remove `DESC` at the end of the query

Comment: Hi Thomas, I only want to display the rows from ID 1 and 2. Now it is showing 4 rows. I want to MySQL select automaticly the first available order_number (lowest one) which has status '1' or '2' and output that for me in a query.

Comment: In this question you meant by the SQL query, so it is better to void talking about what you want to do with the query result. i.e don't regard PHP in the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid a subquery it could looks like:

```
SELECT  scan_activities.*
FROM    scan_activities
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT  MIN(order_number) order_number
    FROM    scan_activities
) t2 ON t2.order_number = scan_activities.order_number
WHERE order_status IN (1,2);
```

Or with subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM scan_activities
WHERE order_number = ( SELECT MIN(order_number) FROM scan_activities WHERE order_status IN (1,2));
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The `AND order_status IN (1,2)` should be in subquery, not the outer select. After that this answer should be correct.

Comment: Perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: @bnxuq Last question, your solutions works perfectly. But now I have the following: The database column ID is unique `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Now I want to select the MIN(id), but If I do that, I only get one record. What I want is to select the MIN(id) if they match also the same order_number.

Comment: @nhatimme Append `ORDER BY ID LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [WHERE](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-where-clause.htm) clause :

```
$query = 'SELECT * FROM scan_activities WHERE order_status = 1 OR order_status = 2 ORDER BY order_number'
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to display ALL the orders. I want only to display the ROWS from the LOWEST order_number which has status '1' or '2'.

Answer (score 0):

Below might help you

```
 SELECT * FROM scan_activities WHERE order_status IN (1,2) 
 ORDER BY order_number
```

Comment: @ThomasRollet Thanks, It's my bad.